# Can we compute $X^n$ faster than $O(\log n)$?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

While reading, I come across a statement saying that $O(\log n)$ is the fastest algorithm for computing the nth power of a number followed by $O(n)$. 
So, is that possible to compute the $n^{th}$ power of a number in $O(1)$ time complexity?

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: You have to be a little more specific about what you mean by 'time complexity'. For instance, when people say they can compute $X^n$ in $O(\log n)$, they specifically mean using $O(\log n)$ _multiplications_; that doesn't mean that the time on a Turing Machine or RAM, for instance, is $O(\log n)$ - in fact, for most sensible definitions of 'compute' it can't be, since it will take $O(n)$ operations just to write the output!

Comment: But 'generically', I believe it can be shown that it takes $O(\log n)$ multiplications because an algorithm for computing $X^n$ with $k$ multiplies can be converted into an algorithm for computing $n$ itself with $k$ adds, and it's known that that requires $\Theta(\log n)$ operations in general.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki thanks for the explanation. So, in other words, what you are saying is the algorithm with a time complexity of $Θ(logn)$ is the fastest in solving this problem, right?

Comment: I'm saying that the algorithm that uses $\Theta(\log n)$ _multiplications_ is the fastest (generic) algorithm, and that $\Theta(\log n)$ here does *not* directly measure the time complexity.